# Multiple buttons only opening most recent modal in code

Tags: javascript, html, css

Very new to coding here, but I am coding a web app, and I want to have two buttons at the top of the page. one to login/create an account, and another to add a review of the page. I added the first button and got it to display a modal when it was pressed, this all worked fine. I then tried to add a second button that would display another modal, but now both buttons only display the second modal.

Each modal had a small 'x' at the top right corner to exit and this also doesn't work now. Here is my code

The style is all in the head.

```
    /* The Modal (background) */
    .modal {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        padding-top: 100px;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); /* Used to grey out the rest of the screen */
    }

    /* Modal Content */
    .modal-content {
        background-color: #fefefe; /* Background colour of Modal */
        margin: auto;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        width: 50%;
    }

    /* The Close Button */
    .close {
        color: #aaaaaa;
        float: right;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

The rest of the code is all in the body.

```
<h2>Modal Testing</h2>

<!-- Buttons to open Modals -->
<button id="loginBtn">Account</button>
<button id="reviewBtn">Add Review</button>

<!-- The Modals -->

<!-- Login/Create Account Modal -->
<div id="loginModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Login details</p>
    <!-- Allows the user to input information-->
    <form action="/action_page.php">
        Username:<br>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="">
        <br>
        Password:<br>
        <input type="password" value="" id="userInput">
        <br><br>
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="visible()">Show Password
    </form>
    <button id="signInBtn">Sign In</button>
    <p>Not got an account? Sign up now!</p>
    <button id="signUpBtn">Sign Up</button>
    <button id="cancelBtn">Cancel</button>

</div>

</div>

<script>
function visible(){
    var x = document.getElementById("userInput");
    if (x.type === "password") {
        x.type = "text";
    } else {
        x.type = "password";
    }
}
</script>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('loginModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("loginBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

<!-- Add Review Modal -->
<div id="addReviewModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Add Review</p>
    <!-- Allows the user to input information-->
    <form action="/review_page.php">
        Location:<br>
        <input type="text" name="location" value="">
        <br>
        Comments:<br>
        <input type="text" name="comments" value="">
        <br>
    </form>
    <button id="submitBtn">Submit Review</button>
    <button id="cancelBtn">Cancel</button>

</div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('addReviewModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("reviewBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: you need to call your second set of variables something different as you have already declared them in the global scope (so all you are doing is overwriting them, which is why the buttons fire the same thing)

Answer (score 3):

You are using your JavaScript in different `<script>` tags. This does not mean that they are seperate blocks, They just get appended to each other. This means, that when you declare the Variable `modal` in one block and then declare it again in the second block, the Variable will get overwrited. I changed the Var names to XXX1 and XXX2.

```js
function visible(){
    var x = document.getElementById("userInput");
    if (x.type === "password") {
        x.type = "text";
    } else {
        x.type = "password";
    }
}

// Get the modal
var modal1 = document.getElementById('loginModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn1 = document.getElementById("loginBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn1.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span1.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal1) {
        modal1.style.display = "none";
    }
}

// Get the modal
var modal2 = document.getElementById('addReviewModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn2 = document.getElementById("reviewBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal2) {
        modal2.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
    .modal {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        padding-top: 100px;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); /* Used to grey out the rest of the screen */
    }

    /* Modal Content */
    .modal-content {
        background-color: #fefefe; /* Background colour of Modal */
        margin: auto;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        width: 50%;
    }

    /* The Close Button */
    .close {
        color: #aaaaaa;
        float: right;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<h2>Modal Testing</h2>

<!-- Buttons to open Modals -->
<button id="loginBtn">Account</button>
<button id="reviewBtn">Add Review</button>

<!-- The Modals -->

<!-- Login/Create Account Modal -->
<div id="loginModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Login details</p>
    <!-- Allows the user to input information-->
    <form action="/action_page.php">
        Username:<br>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="">
        <br>
        Password:<br>
        <input type="password" value="" id="userInput">
        <br><br>
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="visible()">Show Password
    </form>
    <button id="signInBtn">Sign In</button>
    <p>Not got an account? Sign up now!</p>
    <button id="signUpBtn">Sign Up</button>
    <button id="cancelBtn">Cancel</button>

</div>

</div>

<!-- Add Review Modal -->
<div id="addReviewModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Add Review</p>
    <!-- Allows the user to input information-->
    <form action="/review_page.php">
        Location:<br>
        <input type="text" name="location" value="">
        <br>
        Comments:<br>
        <input type="text" name="comments" value="">
        <br>
    </form>
    <button id="submitBtn">Submit Review</button>
    <button id="cancelBtn">Cancel</button>

</div>

</div>
```

Now the buttons open the corresponding modal.

I will post an update if I figured yout the "Close on X" thing.

Sorry for my bad english ;)

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
```

use

```
modal.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
```